# Give moderators ability to set delayed close on questions with insufficient details

Tags: feature-request

I find myself wasting a lot of (moderating) time on questions that are valid, but don't have sufficient details and are hard (short of lucky guess) to try and answer.

1. I need to leave comment asking for details.
2. I need to come back to it reasonably later (days) and check.

I could close them on sight, but that would be way too unwelcoming (a lot of users new to network) and if user wants it reopened (or worse - asks duplicate question with same lacking amount of detail) I just made more work for mods.

It would be great if I could set **delayed close** - "If original user had not edited this question in following X days then close it". Message it to user, put notification with countdown on post itself.

This way moderator only needs to deal with situation once - then either user adds details or system closes it automatically. In both positive and negative outcomes there is no need for repeated moderator involvement. Notice with explanation makes it unnecessary to write individual comments.

Comment: +1 for this feature.